# Platform moves way to the right before performing correctly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, platform

I placed a platform and it is supposed to move left to right from the spot I put it in, but the problem is it moves to the extreme right and then it goes back and forth.  I am using Unity and C#

```
//Left to Right moving platform

public float dirX, moveSpeed;
private bool moveRight = true;

private void Update() 
{
    if (transform.position.x > 4f)
        moveRight = false;
    if (transform.position.x < -4f)
        moveRight = true;
    if (moveRight)
         transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x + moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    else transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x - moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
}
```

Comment: replace 4 and -4 with a variable which you set to transform.position.x in Start method

Answer (score 0):

What is your initial transform position? Is it the origin (0,0,0)? If so, change your code to check:

```
if (transform.position.x < 0f) // this should be your platforms initial transform.position.x value
    moveRight = true;
```

Comment: If I start it over to the right that works. I couldnt get it to work from the spot I put it in

Comment: What is your initial `transform.position`?